# Change $(this) context in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, proxy

This is the function I use to bind 'tap' event on mobile devices. Basically a normal function.

```
bindTapEvent: function(container, selector, run, bindClickAlso){
    var startX, startY, currentX, currentY = 0;
    var moved = false;
    var self;

    if(touchDevice){
        container.on({
            click: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            touchstart: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                self = $(this);
                startX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
                startY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
            },
            touchmove: function(e){
                currentX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
                currentY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
                if(Math.abs(startX - currentX) > 10 || Math.abs(startY - currentY) > 10){
                    moved = true;
                }
            },
            touchend: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                run();
            }
        }, 
        selector
        )
    } else {
        if(bindClickAlso != false){
            container.on('click', selector, function(){
                run();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I make use of it like this:

```
tt.bindTapEvent(container, '.showColumns', function(){
    container.find('.column').addClass('visible');
    $(this).doSomething();
});
```

The only problem is that I cannot (obviously) user $(this) inside somtething like this. I've read about jQuery $.proxy that changes the context, but I cannot get to understand it so I can use it. Is it possible (in my case) to change the context of the anonymous function used in tt.bindTapEvent to that when I use $(this) it is 'stored' and 'used' only in the bindTapEvent function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at .call() and .apply() which let you pass the desired context as the first parameter.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

so in your example instead of `run()` you could use `run.call(this);` so you're passing this as the context for the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bind function defined by the ES5 standard, and supported by all modern browsers (and *shimmable* for IE8 and below)

You call bind right on the function of your choice, and a new function will be returned.

The first parameter passed to `bind` is the object you'd like to be set to `this` inside of the resulting function, and subsequent arguments will be curried.  So for your situation, just adding `.bind(this)` to the anonymous function should work.

```
tt.bindTapEvent(container, '.showColumns', function(){
    container.find('.column').addClass('visible');
    $(this).doSomething(); //should work now
}.bind(this));
```

[More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?action=edit)

Comment: Doesn't it collide with jQuery which has 'bind' as well?

Comment: No - this bind is called right on a function - jQuery's bind is, I assume, defined on the jQuery object itself.

Comment: I understand. Seems great for the future, but mobile Safari lacks support for now.

Comment: I feel that this is by far the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about the [`this` issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), I'd expected you to know about the [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) methods, too :-)

You would need to call the `run`-function in context of the container, respectively of `this` in the listener functions:

```
e.preventDefault();
run.call(this, e);
```

BTW: You seem to declare and initialisize the `var self`, but use it nowhere?